# SQL Server: creating a primary key with SORT_IN_TEMPDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am working on a project where I need to create dozens of nonclustered indexes on various tables that already exist, and I am using this "WITH" clause for my create index statements:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_blah_blah_blah 
ON prt.BlahBlah ([blahID])
WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90);
```

These work fine.

However, in one case, I have a table with 3M records, but no indexes and no primary key at all.  I need to create a primary key, so I want to run something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE prt.AuditLog 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_auditlog PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([RecordID])
WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,      -- option NOT SUPPORTED for alter table
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = ON,       -- option NOT SUPPORTED for alter table
      ONLINE = ON,              -- option NOT SUPPORTED for alter table
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90);
```

But three of the options of the "WITH" clause are not supported for `ALTER TABLE`.

I can live without the `DROP_EXISTING`, but I really need the `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` and `ONLINE` options.

How do I get this done?

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I would just create a new table and select into it

Comment: @paparazzo - I can't do that.  This is in production, and in between the time when I drop the original table and rename the new table to replace the old one, the application might try to write to the table.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to set `Sort_IN_TempDB = ON` here:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/02/20/sql-server-improve-index-rebuild-performance-enabling-sort-tempdb/

```
ALTER INDEX [IndexName] ON [SchemaName].[TableName]
REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON)
GO
```

Comment: @TT.thought of helping providing the link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19178291)

Comment: @GreatBigBore edited the answer..Thanks for explaining

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will need to research this to see what it is doing, but at first glance this does not look like it answers the question.  I want to create a primary key in production, and have it initially sorted and created using the TEMPDB so that it does not interfere with production.  This answer looks like the primary key is already built.

Comment: @Joe Can't you add primary key without SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON option and then alter?

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan - I don't know...   will the initial adding of the primary key cause a sort?  I need to research this